# Manipulation string pointer content in caesar cipher

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to learn string pointers in C using a Caesar cipher, but I'm having trouble.

When I try to replace the buffer value with the cipher text, the buffer value in the calling module does not change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int encrypt(unsigned char *buffer) {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char *temp_buffer;
    
    temp_buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc( strlen(buffer) );
    memset(temp_buffer, '\0', sizeof(temp_buffer));

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
        strcat(temp_buffer, 
               (unsigned char[2]){(unsigned char) (buffer[i] + 2), '\0'} 
              );
    }
    
    buffer = (unsigned char *)temp_buffer;
    printf("%s", buffer); //this one is right, output : jgnnm"umpnf
    
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char *buffer = "hello world";

    printf("%s\n", buffer); //hello world

    encrypt(buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer); //expect jgnnm"umpnf, but output hello world

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `strcpy` but it causes a segmentation fault. Is there another way that can be applied?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems:

- First you forget that `strlen` doesn't count the null-terminator that is needed for strings;
- Second you use `sizeof(temp_buffer)` which is the size of the variable `temp_buffer` which is the same as `sizeof(unsigned char *)`. It does not give the size of the memory you just allocated;
- Then you forget that arguments are passed by value, meaning the value in the call is *copied* into the functions argument variable. Assigning to the argument variable only modifies the local argument variable. Either *return* the new string (which I recommend) or research *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it looks like I'll try to read about emulating pass by reference section than using return.